# pgfplots 3D: z-buffer not working, showing objects in wrong depth-order

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, axis

I'm trying to create a simple 3D figure, using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=9cm, height=9cm,
            axis lines=center,
            z buffer=sort,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            zlabel=$z$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.075)}},
            every axis z label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
            axis line style={stealth-stealth, thick},
            xmin=-4, xmax=4,
            ymin=-4, ymax=4,
            zmin=-4, zmax=4,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            ztick=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot3[surf, fill=blue!5, opacity=0.5, domain=-4:4, samples=5] {0};
        \draw[dashed, thick] (axis cs:-4,-4,-4) -- (axis cs:4,4,4);
        \draw[-stealth, ultra thick, red] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:2,2,2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

I want the positive part of the x-axis to be shown in front of the plane, and not behind it as it is shown now, and the dashed lines on the left side to be behind the plane (and generally for parts closer to the "camera" to hide stuff further away from it). Using `axis on top` doesn't produce the result I'm after.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PGFPlots do not have any z buffer extending outside a single plot itself. To get the desired result, you need to draw the things in the correct order:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=9cm, height=9cm,
axis lines=center,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.075)}},
every axis z label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
axis line style={stealth-stealth, thick},
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
zmin=-4, zmax=4,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
]
\draw[dashed, thick] (-4,-4,-4) -- (0,0,0);
\addplot3[surf, fill=blue!5, opacity=0.5, domain=-4:4, samples=5] {0};
\draw[dashed, thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,4,4);
\draw[-stealth, ultra thick, red] (0,0,0) -- (2,2,2);
\draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D coordinate system with plane]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a = 3;}]
    \draw[<-> , thick,red] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,2) node[right]{$ z $};
    \draw[<->,thick,red] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[left]{$ x $};
    \draw[<->,thick, red] (0,-2,0) -- (0,2,0) node[right]{$ y $}
    ;
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        \draw [blue!30] (-a,-a) grid (a,a); 
    \end{scope}
\draw[-stealth, ultra thick, red] (0,0,0) -- (2,2,2);
\draw[dashed] (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0) --(2,0,0)
 (2,2,0) -- (0,2,0)
 (2,2,2) -- (0,0,2)
 (0,0,0) -- (2,2,0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just an other more manual way to draw the same thing. It also do not solve any z buffer problem.